# Mysql Auto increment without index

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I believe this is not possible, but I ask here to be sure.

Here are my thoughts:

- I want to insert many rows and generate ids for them (using auto increment)
- It is known to be faster to 1) not index, do your inserts and add your index after inserts are done, than 2) creating the index first and do your inserts. This is because of the overhead of indexing during inserts

Since I am doing an insert...select, I cannot generate the ids from the application.

So, basically, what would be perfect would be to have an auto increment that does not need to be indexed.

I don't understand why mysql need an index to implement auto increment? cannot simply store the last inserted id and then increment it?

Any input is welcome!

Comment: An auto_increment field must be defined as the primary key - it's a rule.

Comment: You can generate the numbers in your `insert ... select`. And are you really sure this is a performance problem for you?

Comment: @P.Salmon this is actually incorrect. Only an index is needed. You don't need a PK. Then, I am asking why it's a rule. If you read my question, it is trivial that I know this... sorry for being rude ^^

Comment: @juergend do you advise something like "INSERT ... SELECT \@id = \@id + 1"? That would be an option I think! We are working with a huge amount of data insertions, so if they can be 10% faster by indexing after... I am looking for all optimizations ;-)

Comment: @Vincent Pazeller thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an ID like this

```
insert into destination_table (col_id, col2, col3)
select @rank := @rank + 1, colX, colY
from source_table
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
order by some_column
```